# Sum Values Based On Other Column Value

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-finance

I am trying to do a formula for:

- **NUMBER OF SHARES** per sector - should count all shares from column **E:E** in column **I:I** based on **sector**

[image]

**TABLE:**

| SYMBOL | NAME | TYPE | SECTOR | OWNED SHARES | SHARES PRICE |  | SECTOR | NUMBER OF SHARES | TOTAL PER SECTOR |  | TYPE | TOTAL PER STOCK TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABML | American Battery Technology Co | Growth | - | 100 | 79 |  | - |  |  |  | Growth |  |
| BABA | Alibaba Group Holding Ltd - ADR | Growth | Consumer Cyclical | 200 | 12574 |  | Consumer Cyclical |  |  |  | Dividend |  |
| BAC | Alibaba Group Holding Ltd - ADR | Dividend | Financial | 1000 | 35460 |  | Financial |  |  |  |  |  |
| LI | Li Auto Inc | Growth | Consumer Cyclical | 300 | 4791 |  | Energy |  |  |  |  |  |
| MMP | Magellan Midstream Partners, L.P. | Dividend | Energy | 10000 | 515700 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| MPLX | MPLX LP | Dividend | Energy | 20000 | 662000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**DEMO**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sBVb29p0yYcn3-CI3TvG6noN8AQPE2zxDCKojUcb2Nw/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

I tried
`=sumif(D:D; H2; F:F)` it works, but I wanted this function to be repeated for every value in column **H** once there is a new value.

Comment: Ask only one question per post. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237

Comment: So let me see if I understand this right. The Number of Shares is the sum of the Owned Shares column that matches the sector? The Total per Sector is the sum of the Shares Price column that also matches the sector? And the Total Per Stock Type is the sum of the Shares Price column that match the Type column?

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Gabriel Carballo Updated my question with ```=sumif(D:D; H2; F:F)``` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your formula for I2, then copy it down however far you need it:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,$H2,E:E)
```

Here is your formula for J2, then copy it down however far you need it:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,$H2,F:F)
```

And finally, your formula for M2, then copy it down however far you need it:

```
=SUMIF(C:C, $L2,F:F)
```

Comment: Hi @LASheets thank you for your answer, yes, **SUMIF** works, however, I wanted this function to be repeated for every value in column **H** once there is a new value

Comment: Try this one @vohratom. You'll have to change the formula for each of your columns, but this should work for you. The important piece is using the SUMIF inside of the ARRAYFORMULA. The IF(ISBLANK()) part is just to eliminate a whole list of 0s for blank cells in H. =ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(H2:H),,SUMIF($D$2:$D,$H$2:$H,$E$2:$E)))

Answer (score 1):

You may as well try:

Number of shares:

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$7,$D$2:$D$7,$H$2:$H$7)
```

Total per Sector:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$7,$D$2:$D$7,$H$2:$H$7)
```

Total per Stock type:

```
=SUMIF(C:C, $L2, F:F)
```

On all three scenarios you need to drag down the formula for it to display the results.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel Carballo thank you, I answered in a similar way to **LASheets** in the comment above this one - in short, I just wanted this function to be repeated once there is a new line in column **** without having to copy-paste the function :-)